# What causes DBD::ODBC::st fetchrow_array failed: st_fetch/SQLFetch and how to avoid it?

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash

EDIT1:

I don't actually get an empty array as stated below. Instead, I get an empty response body because of the following exception:

```
DBD::ODBC::st fetchrow_array failed: st_fetch/SQLFetch (long truncated DBI attribute LongTruncOk not set and/or LongReadLen too small) (SQL-HY000) [state was HY000 now 01004]
```

Which I can see there are posts about. I will look at those to see if I can fix this on my on. Will edit if not successful.

---

First let me start by saying, I do not know Perl well at all. This could be a careless error — I hope it is. I am building a hash from an array that is returned from SQL or from JavaScript on the front-end and one of the keys in the hash, "short-desc" needs to have the value which in the code below will be coming from a SQL database.

```
BFHHOTH 15x24S/S +2 UP-HNDWHL-UNSPOKED-GALV 15"x24" flush escape hatch w/hinge, internal handwheel, T-handle on top steel cover and ring
```

However with the code (removed unnecessary cases from switch):

```
#!perl
use Switch;
use DBI;
use JSON;
use CGI qw /param/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError);
use URI::Encode;
use URI::Escape;

my $gzip_ok;

my $accept_encoding = $ENV{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING};
if ( $accept_encoding && $accept_encoding =~ /\bgzip\b/ ) {
 # $gzip_ok = 1;
}
print "Content-Type: application/json\n";
if ($gzip_ok) {
    print "Content-Encoding: gzip\n";
}
print "\n";

my $action = param('ACTION');

my %jsonData;
my @jsonArray;

my $azDSN = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Uid=me;Pwd={myPass};Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;');

switch ($action) {
 case "GETINFO" {
    my $paramID = param('ID');
    getInfo($paramID);
     my $json_text = JSON->new->pretty->utf8->encode( \@jsonArray );
    if ($gzip_ok) {
        my $zipText;
        gzip \$json_text, \$zipText,
            or die "gzip failed: $GzipError\n";
        print $zipText;
    }
    else {
        print $json_text;
    }
  }
}

sub getInfo {
 my $myID = $_[0];
 my $statement = <<"SQL";
   SELECT
     trefQuoteItemsID,
     quote_position,
     description,
     comments
   FROM
     myDB.dbo.myTable where tID = $myID;
 SQL
 my $sti = $azDSN->prepare($statement) or die $statement;
 $sti->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
 while ( my @row = $sti->fetchrow_array ) {
     my %tempData;

     %tempData = (
         "tref"                      => $row[0],
         "position"                  => $row[1],
         "short_desc"                => $row[2],
         "comments"                  => $row[3]
     );
     $jsonArray[$count] = {%tempData};
     $count++;
 }
}
```

An empty array is returned to me on the front-end.

Oddly, if the string is:

```
BFHHOTH 15x24S/S +2 UP-HNDWHL-UNSPOKED-
```

the array contains the correct object. 
But empty again if the string is:

```
BFHHOTH 15x24S/S +2 UP-HNDWHL-UNSPOKED-G
```

Have also tried with strings:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwe  #length is 39
```

which lets the hash gets built and:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwer #length is 40
```

which will return an empty array so hash doesn't get built.

Are there any Perl gurus who have any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Here's how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @ikegami working on that right now, sorry about that

Comment: You will definitely need to read http://bobby-tables.com/ to learn about SQL injection

Comment: @glennjackman thanks, new to sql and this is work i inherited from someone else, so the code isn't really 'mine' so i have been fearing some issue like that. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it's related to "long object" columns.

DBD::ODBC says:

> You can retrieve a lob in chunks like this:
>
> ```
> $sth->bind_col($column, undef, {TreatAsLOB=>1});
> while(my $retrieved = $sth->odbc_lob_read($column, \my $data, $length)) {
>     print "retrieved=$retrieved lob_data=$data\n";
> }
> ```
>
> NOTE: to retrieve a lob like this you must first bind the lob column specifying BindAsLOB or DBD::ODBC will 1) bind the column as normal and it will be subject to LongReadLen and b) fail odbc_lob_read.
>
> NOTE: Some database engines and ODBC drivers do not allow you to retrieve columns out of order (e.g., MS SQL Server unless you are using cursors). In those cases you must ensure the lob retrieved is the last (or only) column in your select list.
>
> NOTE: You can retrieve only part of a lob but you will probably have to call finish on the statement handle before you do anything else with that statement. When only retrieving part of a large lob you could see a small delay when you call finish as some protocols used by ODBC drivers send the lob down the socket synchronously and there is no way to stop it (this means the ODBC driver needs to read all the lob from the socket even though you never retrieved it all yourself).
>
> NOTE: If your select contains multiple lobs you cannot read part of the first lob, the second lob then return to the first lob. You must read all lobs in order and completely or read part of a lob and then do no further calls to odbc_lob_read.

There's no mention if you can retrieve a lob any other way, so I don't know if you have to do it this way, but at least you know one way. But I believe you can work around the problem by increasing the connection's `LongReadLen` attribute.

You should be able to set the attribute as follows:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwd, {
   ...,
   LongReadLen => ...,
});
```

You should also be able to set the attribute as follows:

```
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = ...;
```

Hopefully, someone can give you a better answer.

Comment: Yep, I got it working by adding LongReadLen value to the database handler. Thanks!